# Infinite scroll not working in chrome on zoom in/zoom out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I am using this infinite scroll script. This code works well in Firefox and opera but does not work in chrome when I zoom in/zoom out.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if (($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight()) >= $(document).height() - 100) {
    bookSeach.loadBooksOnScroll(count);
    count += 10;
  }
});
```

Comment: I replaced `bookSeach.loadBooksOnScroll(count);` with `console.log(count)` and run the code in Chrome and it logs out the count on scroll and zoom doesn't break this.